# Join strings skips first line

Tags: python

My Code:

```
f=open(keywords_file,"r")
keywords=f.read().split("\n")[0:-1]
f.close()
os.remove(keywords_file)
up.enter_keywords(",".join(keywords))
up.quit()
```

My file looks like:

```
Keyword
Keyword2
Keyword3
keyword4
```

The problem I noticed:

enter_keywords join skips the first line so my end results:

```
keyword2,keyword3,keyword4
```

I need:

```
keyword,keyword2,keyword3,keyword4
```

Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 with open(keywords_file, 'r') as f:
     keywords = ",".join(line.strip() for line in f)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are omitting it when you make a slice:

```
    keywords=f.read().split("\n")[0:-1]
```

instead, you should just do the following:

```
    keywords = [word for word in f]
```

Comment: oh this is a nice solution as well will try it in a moment thank you! Which one should I choose

Comment: You should use the other solution, my answer just shows your mistake.

Comment: @JoJoMe: To explain a little more, the second index in a slice is exclusive. `-1` refers to the last element, so `[0:-1]` gives a copy of all but the last element. Just leave out the index to get everything, i.e. `[0:]` or just `[:]`. In this case, it's completely unnecessary to make a copy, though, because you're not using the original result of the `split` method anyway.

Comment: @Rörd so what your recommendation of code to use? Just cange my [0:-1] to [0:] or [:]?

Comment: @JoJoMe: Since you don't need to make a copy, you can just leave out the slicing completely and write only `keywords=f.read().split("\n")`. The other changes from the answers you got are also worthwhile to consider. (Particularly to use the `with` statement to take care of closing the file automatically. Whether to `read` and then `split` the whole file or reading it line by line right away with a list/generator expression is more a matter of taste or optimization.)

Comment: @JoJoMe: Though actually, you should use `keywords = f.read().splitlines()` if you keep the first approach. I've only now remembered that `split("\n")` returns an empty string as the last element if the last line ends with a line break, and so the `[0:-1]` slice may actually make sense. Just avoid that issue by using `splitlines()`, or reading the file line by line.